# Javascript sort and filter array by 2 properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, filter

I want to keep a list of the highest scores by date:

i.e

Name: Player A | Score: 2000 | Date: 2020-04-15

Name: Player B| Score: 2001 | Date: 2020-04-16

*However i sometimes get a greater score but lower date:*

Name: Player A| Score: 2000 | Date: **2020-01-12**

Name: Player B| Score: 2001 | Date: **2019-12-20**

```js
// should only return: a and c in order.
let arr = [
{name: c, score: 6, date: 5-20-2021},
{name: b, score: 2, date: 5-20-2020},
{name: a, score: 3, date: 5-20-2019}
]
arr.sort((a, b) => (a.score > b.score) ? 1 : -1)
arr.filter((a, b) => (a.submitted > b.submitted) ? 1 : -1)
```

Comment: Please post your array with representative sample data.

Comment: Idk know if this is your issue, but filter expects a Boolean, not a 1, -1 like sort

Answer (score 0):

**filter method provide three arguments:**

1. current element
2. index of current element
3. array

Therefore, you try to compare submitted with undefined.
If you need to get two element from a sorted array, you can just use ***splice*** method

```
arr.sort((a, b) => b.score - a.score).splice(0, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put both conditions when you sort:

```html
<script>
let arr = [
{name: "i", score: 16, date: 2-20-2021},
{name: "h", score: 6, date: 5-25-2021},
{name: "g", score: 6, date: 5-20-2022},
{name: "f", score: 6, date: 5-10-2021},
{name: "e", score: 16, date: 5-20-1021},
{name: "d", score: 6, date: 5-20-2001},
{name: "c", score: 6, date: 5-20-2021},
{name: "b", score: 2, date: 5-20-2020},
{name: "a", score: 3, date: 5-20-2019}
]

arr.sort((a, b) => (a.score < b.score) && (a.date < b.date) ? 1 : -1)
console.log(arr)
</script>
```